# Error in parameters..

Tags: c

Sorry for repost. Have another 2 codes and with 1 problem. Both of  these codes will show me up "Error in parameters" when I am going to run them.

First code -

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
main (argc, argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
    int fd1, fd2, fd3;
    int nbytes, mode, nbytes1;
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    if(argc < 3) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Error in parametrs\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
    }
    if ((fd1 = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) < 0 ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can`t open file %s\n",
            argv[1]);
    exit(1);
    }
    if ((fd2 = open(argv[2],O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, mode)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can`t create new file %s\n", argv[2]);
            exit(1);
    }
    if ((fd3 = open(argv[3], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, mode)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can`t create new file %s\n", argv[3]);
            exit(1);
    }

    while((nbytes = read(fd1, buf, BUFSIZ))> 0) {
            if(write(fd2, buf, nbytes) < 0) {

            fprintf(stderr, "Write error\n"); break;
           }
            if(write(fd3, buf, nbytes) < 0) {

            fprintf(stderr, "Write error\n"); break;
           }

    }



    if(nbytes < 0) fprintf(stderr, "Reading error\n");
    close(fd1);
    close(fd2);
    close(fd3);
    exit(0);
}
```

Second one, has the same problem when I gonna run it "Error in parameters"

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
main (argc, argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
    int fd1, fd2, fd3;
    int nbytes, mode, nbytes1;
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    if(argc < 3) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Error in parametrs\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
    }
    if ((fd1 = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) < 0 ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can`t open file %s\n",
            argv[1]);
    exit(2);
    }
    if ((fd2 = open(argv[2],O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, mode)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can`t create new file %s\n", argv[2]);
            exit(3);
    }
    if ((fd3 = open(argv[3], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, mode)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can`t create new file %s\n", argv[3]);
            exit(4);
    }

    while((nbytes = read(fd1, buf, BUFSIZ))> 0) {
            if(write(fd2, buf, nbytes) < 0) {

            fprintf(stderr, "Write error\n");
            break;
           }
            if(write(fd3, buf, nbytes) < 0) {

            fprintf(stderr, "Write error\n");
            break;
           }

    }



    if(nbytes < 0) fprintf(stderr, "Reading error\n");
    close(fd1);
    close(fd2);
    close(fd3);
    exit(0);
}
```

Sorry again for repost....

Comment: And what is the commandline?

Comment: Inputs, outputs, error messages, what you found out when you ran it under your debugger and stepped through.....

Comment: The most likely cause is that `argc < 3`.

Comment: @Martin James It didn't show up any error messages or in debugger anything.

Comment: How do you run the program ? Did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean)?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Through CodeBlocks using K&R compilers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must give to your program 3 arguments. This is caused by this line

```
if(argc < 3) {
```

which signify "if the number of arguments is below 3".

Edit :

This line is wrong because you need 4 parameters as the program name is the first parameter. Change this line to

```
if(argc < 4) {
```

And just call your program this way :

```
./program file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: The program name is counted among `argc`.

Comment: I hadn't even noticed the OP accessing `argv[3]`, well spotted.

Comment: Where do I have to add "./program file1 file2 file3" ?

Comment: Sorry, I never used code::blocks. Try to do it using the command line, in a shell. Otherwise, perhaps there is an option in code::blocks that permit to give arguments.

Comment: According to my internet search, you must use Projects->set programs' arguments and put the three file names.